# Does css require that I use double dashes (--) in front of variable names?

Tags: css, css-variables

I noticed when I use css variables I need to put two dashes in front of them:

```
:root {
    --main-txt-color: blue; 
}

#div1 {
    color: var(--main-txt-color);
}
```

I'd rather not have double dashes in the beginning of the variable names. I'd rather name it in a way that I choose to for example:

```
:root {
        myvar: blue; 
    }
```

Is there a way to do this or do I need to use double dashes?

Comment: https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/a/311798

Comment: and how you browser will make the difference between *custom properties* and *normal properies* ?

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/--*

Comment: @SooriyaDasanayake that isn't stackoverflow, therefore it's not a duplicate

Comment: @TemaniAfif what do you mean? every time I use the variable I put "var()" around it.

Comment: @foreyez you only use *var()* when you will evalute the property and before you need to define the property .. so if you set *mycolor:red* how the browser will know if it's a custom property or not? ... the *--* are used to allow the browser to make the difference

Comment: @TemaniAfif it's inside of :root that's how it knows it's a custom variable

Comment: no, custom properties can be used anywhere, not only inside root

Comment: @TemaniAfif do you mean used or defined

Comment: both, they can be used and defined anywhere

Comment: `Custom properties are ordinary properties, so they can be declared on any element, are resolved with the normal inheritance and cascade rules, can be made conditional with @media and other conditional rules, can be used in HTML’s style attribute, can be read or set using the CSSOM, etc` -->https://www.w3.org/TR/css-variables-1/#using-variables

Comment: You’re required to use the syntax of the language in which you’re writing, therefore yes: you’re “*stuck with using double dashes.*”

Answer (score 2):

## [Custom Properties](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/--*)

> Custom properties participate in the cascade: the value of such a custom property is that from the declaration decided by the cascading algorithm.

You must use `--` in variables, otherwise, it will result in an error.

### Legal Statement

(With `--`)

```css
:root {
  --my-color: #5637a8;
}
body {
  background-color: var(--my-color);
}
```

### Illegal Statement

(Without the use of `--`)

```css
:root {
  my-color: #85637d;
}
body {
  background-color: var(my-color);
}
```

Comment: Yeah you go to prison for this :D

Answer (score 1):

Double dashes are used in custom properties defined by the user.

On the other hand, CSS properties that already exist in the standard do not have double dashes.

For example, you can define the style within a *.css* file or within 
 inside :

```
body{
color: blue;
background-color: white;
}

h1 { 
    font-family: "Times New Roman";
    font-size: 20;
    font-weight: bold;    
    align: center;
    margin-top: 10;
    margin-bottom: 10;
    margin-left: 0;
    margin-right: 0;
 }
```